# Replace DB parameters in a string from a textfile

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am writing a code to read a string from a text file and then change the `DBnames` parameter (för surrounded by asterisks) to a different name that starts with `NEWDB + textBox.Text`. I also want to change the `DOMAINDB` to `DOMAIN + txtbox.Text`

My current code only searches for the specific word using `string.StartsWith`.
But I'm looking for a way that will read the values I need to change based on the comma separation.

here's my current dirty code: (It somewhat works, but I'm looking for a way to make it more dynamic)

```
CurrentFilePath = NextFilePath(FilePaths, FileEnum) 'defined in previous section
OriginalFileLines = File.ReadAllLines(CurrentFilePath) 'defined in previous section
NewFileLines.Clear()
Dim DataDB = "NEWDB" + txtbox.Text.ToUpper()
Dim DomainDB = "DOMAIN" + txtbox.Text.ToUpper()
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()
For Each line In OriginalFileLines
    Dim arr = line.Split(",")
    Dim NewLine As New StringBuilder()
'    arr(6) = DataDB
'    sb.AppendLine(String.Join(",", arr))
'Next

For Each word In arr
    If word.StartsWith("DATADB") Then
       NewLine.Append(",NEWDB" + txtOrgID.Text.ToUpper) 'Change "DATADB%" to "NEWDATADB{txtbox.txt}"

    ElseIf word.Contains("*") Then
          NewLine.Append(",*" + txtServerName.Text) 'Change "%*%" to "*{ServerName}"

    Else
          NewLine.Append(IIf(Array.IndexOf(arr, word) > 0, ",", "") + word) 'Comma if not first word
    End If
Next
NewFileLines.Add(NewLine.ToString)
File.WriteAllLines(CurrentFilePath, NewFileLines.ToArray)
```

Actual Lines Inside TextFile:

```
SSA,SystemA,,YES,YES,*SERVERNAME,**DATADB**,Admin,Passw0rd!,,,MS-SQL
SSB,SystemB,,NO,YES,*SERVERNAME,**DOMAINDB**,Admin,Passw0rd!,,,MS-SQL
SSC,SystemC,,YES,YES,*SERVERNAME,**DOMAINDB**,Admin,Passw0rd!,,,MS-SQL
```

Comment: Is the database always `arr[6]`? if so... could you perhaps just check the value of `arr[6]` ?

Comment: IS this as csv file format? If so, I would recommend: http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/
It can read / write csvs really easily and your best bet would be to acess the "datadb" column...

Comment: Marc, yes the database is always on Array6.

Comment: Christian, is some way, yes its a CSV. I'll check the link you sent

Comment: I'm just starting to code in VB and code samples with your suggestions would be great! Thanks

Comment: You'll of course be wanting to encrypt the credentials in the file, and make heavy use of parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim databases As New List(Of String)()
Dim words() As String
Dim txtLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(sFilePath)

For Each sLine As String In txtLines
    words = sLine.Split(","c)
    words(6) = NEWDB + textBox.Text
    sLine = String.Join(",", words)
Next

File.WriteAllLines(sFilePath, txtLines)
```

Comment: SysDragon, Thanks but when I tried this approach, my overall code bomb out. I've edited my original post and hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to replace the contents of the line at the 6th column (starting from zero) with a new value.
If this is the case, the you could reach directly this index, write a new value there and then append to a stringbuilder where you can recover the new text.

```
Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
For Each line In OriginalFileLines
    Dim arr = line.Split(",")
    if arr(6).StartsWith("**DATADB") then
         arr(6) = "NEWDB" & txtNewDbName.Text.ToUpper()

    Else if(arr(6).StartsWith("**DOMAINDB")) then
         arr(6) = arr(6).Substring(2,8) & txtNewDbName.Text.ToUpper()

    End if
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", arr))
Next

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString())
```

I suppose that OriginalFileLines is an array of strings where each string is a line from your CSV file. Also, there is no error checking here. The lines after the comma split should have at least 7 columns (index 6 is the 7th element)

Not clear if you have or not the asterisks in the input text.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I tried to integrate the code but I'm getting errors. Some of your lines has been commented out because I can't make it to work. I've edited and explained a bit my original post. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Did you get an error message or it is just not what you want? Please add an example of what is the expected output of the procedure

Comment: Hi Steve, this is the scenario that I want.

If textbox = 'AX111'

SSA,SystemA,,YES,YES,*SERVERNAME,NEWDBAX111,Admin,Passw0rd!,,,MS-SQL
SSB,SystemB,,NO,YES,*SERVERNAME,DOMAINDBAX111,Admin,Passw0rd!,,,MS-SQL
SSC,SystemC,,YES,YES,*SERVERNAME,DOMAINDBAX111,Admin,Passw0rd!,,,MS-SQL